# Arizona - continued fees after request for termination

Tags: divorce, fees, arizona

I changed law firms for divorce representation in arizona, due to not being satisfied with the initial law firm.

After notifying the first law firm that I would like to terminate their services and obtain the remainder of the retainer fees I paid them I had to contact them three more times to receive my money back. When receiving my money back (after checking with them how much money I have left, when terminating) I saw that every call I made to inquire about getting my money back was charged $350. Is that legal? The action and the sum charged? Is there anything I can do about this?

The legal representation costs I have to spend are not within my means, and any penny counts, I also feel like there isn't much I can do to protect myself from any type of made up charges.

Comment: When you called to dun them, did they trick you into discussing other business? What did they put on the billing notes?

Comment: Lawyers can suddenly become very nice to you when you mention filing a complaint against them with their bar association, i.e. for an issue like those extra fees they charged you. See The State Bar of Arizona Lawyer Regulation Office (LRO) https://www.azbar.org/for-the-public/concerns-about-your-lawyer/

Comment: other business was not discussed, but the calls to inquire about getting the money back were charged the same way as previous phone calls to ask about the case

Comment: @BlueDogRanch, thanks for the link, but does this behavior count as misconduct?

Comment: The regulation office decides if it is misconduct. But simply suggesting to the law firm that you're going to file a complaint against them often works wonders.